# Gradient of one layer w.r.t another layer when there is an input layer (and no value for the input)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I have a network written in tensorflow keras functional API.
I'd like to use the gradient of one layer w.r.t to the previous layer as input for another layer.
I tried gradient tape and tf.gradients and none of them worked. I get the following error:

`ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.`

There is no input at this point and I have input layer.

Is it possible to do this in tenserflow?

My code:

```
def Geo_branch(self, geo_inp):
        Fully_Connected1 = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(128, activation='tanh'))(geo_inp)
        Fully_Connected2 = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh'))(Fully_Connected1)
        return Fully_Connected2

@tf.function
def geo_extension(self, geo_branch):
    Fully_Connected = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(100, activation='tanh'))(geo_branch)
    geo_ext = layers.LSTM(6,
                          activation="tanh",
                          recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
                          unroll=False,
                          use_bias=True,
                          name='Translation'
                          )(Fully_Connected)

    grads = tf.gradients(geo_ext, geo_branch)
    return geo_ext, grads

inp_geo = layers.Input(shape=(self.time_size, 6), name='geo_input')
Geo_branch = Geo_branch(inp_geo)
geo_ext, grads = geo_extension(Geo_branch)
```

Any solution is appreciated. It doesn't have to be GradientTape, if there is any other way to compute these gradients.

Comment: Is there a reason that the two portions of the network are separated? Why not just put them all in the same "layer"? I'll post an answer and you can tell me if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just inherit from tensorflow's `Layer` class and creating your own custom Layer. Also, it would probably be beneficial to put everything under one call so as to minimize the likelihood that there are disconnections in the graph.

**Example**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from typing import List
from typing import Optional
from typing import Tuple
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed


class CustomGeoLayer(Layer):
  """``CustomGeoLayer``."""
  def __init__(self, num_units: List[int], name: Optional[str] = None):
    super().__init__(name=name)
    self.num_units = num_units
    self.dense_0 = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_units[0], activation="tanh"))
    self.dense_1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_units[1], activation="tanh"))
    self.dense_2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_units[2], activation="tanh"))
    self.rnn = LSTM(units=num_units[3], activation="tanh",
                    recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
                    unroll=False, use_bias=True,
                    name="Translation")
    
  @tf.function
  def call(self,
           input_tensor: tf.Tensor,
           training: bool = True) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    x = self.dense_0(input_tensor)
    x = self.dense_1(x)
    r = self.dense_2(x)
    x = self.rnn(r, training=training)
    return x, tf.gradients(x, r)[0]


# create model
x_in = Input(shape=(10, 6))
x_out = CustomGeoLayer([128, 64, 100, 6])(x_in)
model = Model(x_in, x_out)

# fake input data
arr = tf.random.normal((3, 10, 6))

# forward pass
out, g = model(arr)

print(out.shape)
# (3, 6)

print(g.shape)
# (3, 10, 100)
```